# Standardization of out-of-sample data

Tags: machine-learning, outliers, standardization

I have a panel (N firms across 10 years) dataset on which I want to estimate and test a prediction model $f$:

\begin{equation}
y = f(x).
\end{equation}

Following common practice, I split my data into two parts: training data and test data. My training data consists of the first 9 years and my test data consists of the last 1 year. I also standardize my training data per cross section, i.e. per year.

Now, I want to also standardize my independent test variables, i.e. my test input. My intuition tells me that in order to avoid data leakage, I should be using the training data mean and standard deviation in order to standardize my test data. This is also explicitly mentioned in several Stack Overflow threads, e.g. [Thread Example](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27615/should-we-apply-normalization-to-test-data-as-well).

(1) However, how do I do this in my specific example? I have nine different means and nine different standard deviations, as I do not standardize my training data one time, but nine times. Do I just take the latest (i.e. the ninth cross section) mean and standard deviation to standardize my test data?

(2) What about winsorization? If I winsorize my training data per cross-section and want to winsorize my test input data, how do I proceed? The answer to this should in principle be the same one as to (1) I suppose.

Comment: "Outlier treatment" is mentioned in the title but not in the question if I see it correctly.

Comment: "I do not standardize my training data one time, but nine times" - this looks strange to me. I assume that your prediction model does not take into account the time, i.e., from which year data are. (If it does, explain that in the question.) You are just predicting the $y$ from the $x$. But this means that the $x$ need to be the same in different years, which you would destroy by standardising them differently every year.